# Can't connect to MySQL with XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I have used XAMPP many times before and this has never happened. I do not know what's wrong with it, I have not changed anything in the configuration files.

This is what I get when trying to access localhost/phpmyadmin.
[image: Picture of phpMyAdmin not being able to connect]

I can use mysql with my CLI however, using login root (using password: NO).
[image: CLI showing that I can access my database.]

Here is my configuration file for phpMyAdmin:

```
...

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

...

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

...
```

Comment: If I change the password to NULL instead of ' ', it gives me " Missing connection parameters!
" when trying to access localhost/phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem came with me. It was a permission issue for me with the C: drive. Give the write permission to the xampp folder. I uninstalled it and installed again. Instead of C:\Program files installed directly in C:. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

Please run following commands.

```
    #mysqld --skip-grant-tables
    #mysql -u root mysql

    MariaDB [mysql]> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOUR_PASSWORD') 
                     where USER='root';
     MariaDB [mysql]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score -1):

restart your computer & it may solve your problem.